# VirtualBox 5.2.x fails to install on Mac osx Mojave (10.14) - I know it's old, but somethings new, please read on

Tags: virtualbox, macos-mojave

**Brief History**

I was running Mac osx Sierra and virtualbox was already running without any issues. I upgraded to Mojave and it failed to start with errors. On further research I found out it's common and there are tons of solutions out there which already worked. BUT this one is stubborn.

**Here's what I tried till now**

1. Tried to update Virtualbox and the installation failed with the infamous screen stating - The installation failed, contact the software manufacturer for assistance. Ordeal begins.
2. Checked under "System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General" hoping for it will let me know that it stopped Oracle from running bla bla - NOPE! Nothing in there.
3. Tried uninstalling Virtualbox from the script which is provided inside the mounted drive. It uninstalled everything, retried installation - same result as 1.
4. Tried disabling gatekeeper on Mac using the command `sudo spctl --master-disable`. Tried reinstalling, same result - Failed. Also nothing under the General tab for me to allow manually.
5. Tried various combinations of above steps with restarting OS, nothing changed, same result.

I would appreciate any assistance to solve this issue which has left me clueless. Most of the threads on internet got the notification from OS under the system pref dialog to manually allow the installation. But for me it never shows up and I'm stuck with this.

I can share more details if anyone needs them. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case it helps anyone. These are the steps eventually helped me:

1. I had to clean install Mojave (after taking backup - please don't forget to take backup)
2. Install a Mojave compatible VirtualBox (5.2.26).
3. This time "System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General" showed me the message that the OS has stopped the Oracle, you are "the one" who can "allow" it to run. Clicked Allow.
4. Reinstalled VirtualBox, felt satisfied staring at the green tick mark and the "successfully installed" message.

And that's it. So all it took was a weekend, couple of internet restore of Mac OSX and numerous tries and there's my shiny new VirtualBox installation.

Thank you community.